# Query to return only one matching item in a nested array

Tags: mongodb

I have the following MongoDB document:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "item1",
      "subitems": [
        {
          "id": "subitem1",
          "value": 1
        },
        {
          "id": "subitem2",
          "value": 2
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "item2",
      "subitems": [
        {
          "id": "subitem3",
          "value": 3
        },
        {
          "id": "subitem4",
          "value": 4
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to write a query returning only the subitem matching a specified id, for example:

```
{
  "id": "subitem4",
  "value": 4
}
```

or, if not possible, return the item with only the matching subitem:

```
{
  "id": "item2",
  "subitems": [
    {
      "id": "subitem4",
      "value": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

I was expecting this query to work but it returns a non-matching subitem:

```
db.getCollection('automation').find({"items.subitems.id":"subitem4"}, {"items.subitems.$": 1})
```

returns

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e345abfb6c3d9ca7203a33e"),
    "items" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "item2",
            "subitems" : [ 
                {
                    "id" : "subitem3",
                    "value" : 3
                }, 
                {
                    "id" : "subitem4",
                    "value" : 4
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem with using `$elemMatch` or `$` would be it would only bring first matched document which wouldn't be the case if you've multiple objects in `subitems` matching required criteria. Try this query :

```
db.getCollection('automation').aggregate([
    /** Filtering out collection for docs which has subitem4 atleast in any one object of subitems  */
    { $match: { 'items.subitems.id': 'subitem4' } },
    { $unwind: '$items' },
    /** replacing items, it will either be [] or [{"id" : "subitem4","value" : 4}] */
    {
        $addFields: {
            items: { $filter: { input: "$items.subitems", as: "item", cond: { $eq: ['subitem4', "$$item.id"] } } }
        }
    },
    /** unwinding will remove docs with items : [] & in other case bring object out of array */
    { $unwind: '$items' },
    /** group on _id & push all items from different subitems to one field : items */
    { $group: { '_id': '$_id', items: { $push: '$items' } } }
])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vFkGDuehztd)

Comment: Are you saying that this could be simplified if we suppose that only one subitem is matching?

Comment: @jaudo : correct, what is your scenario? This query can work either way though

Comment: My scenario is that the subitem id is unique, so a simpler query using $elemMatch could be fine if it is possible

Comment: @jaudo : my bad, I've tried with `$elemMatch` it seems to not work cause of array of arrays..